# Can operators be stored in variables?

Tags: matlab, variables, while-loop, operators, eval

This is a thought example of what I am thinking of:

```
test = 'x > 0';

while str2func(test)
   Do your thing
   x=x-1;
end
```

Is it possible to store whole logical operations in a variable like this?

Of course the `str2func` will break here. If it *is* possible this function will likely be something else. And I have only added apostrophes to the `test` variable content, because I cannot think of what else would be the storing method.

I can see it usefull when sending arguments to functions and alike. But mostly I'm just wondering, because I have never seen it done in any programming language before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* store the textual representation of a function in a variable and evaluate it, for example

```
test = 'x > 0';
eval(test)
```

should result in 1 or 0 depending on x's value.

But you *shouldn't* use `eval` for reasons too-often covered here on SO for me to bother repeating.  You should instead become familiar with functions and function handles.  For example

```
test =  @(x)x>0
```

makes `test` a handle to a function which tests whether its argument is greater than 0 or not.

Many languages which are interpreted at run-time, as opposed to compiled languages, have similar capabilities.